# How to extend React types to support html attributes as props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given a component that takes custom props as well as html attribute props, how should the interface for such a component be created? Ideally, the interface would also handle react-specific html props such as using `className` instead of `class`.

This is the usage example for which I am trying to find the right interface:

```
<MyComponent customProp='value' style={{textAlign: 'center'}}  />
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
interface IMyComponentProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  customProp: string;
}
```

UPD:
@ddek mentioned intersections `&`.

I would like to warn you about the following issue with that approach.

```js
interface A {
  onClick: () => void;
}

interface B {
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
}

// Typescript does not complain. This is not good
type AB = A & B;
const a: AB = {
  onClick: () => {}
};


// TS2320: Interface 'AB2' cannot simultaneously extend types 'A' and 'B'.
// Named property 'onClick' of types 'A' and 'B' are not identical.

interface AB2 extends A, B {

}

// TS2430: Interface 'AC' incorrectly extends interface 'A'.
//   Types of property 'onClick' are incompatible.  
//   Type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void' is not
// assignable to type '() => void'.
interface AC extends A {
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
}
```

Comment: Regarding interface AC extends A, how can we override the default onClick from A? I've tried Omit, Pick/Exclude, custom Override type, but none of these get rid of the 'incompatible' error. I feel like there must be a way...

Comment: interface B extends Omit<A, 'onclick'> { 
      onClick: (foo: string) => void;
 }
function (b: B) {
    b.onlick({foo: "bar"});
}

it should work

Answer (score 6):

Yozi is right but there is another way, which demonstrates a typescript (and general FP) feature which you may not be familiar with if you're coming from something like C# or Java.

```
interface MyCustomProps {
    customProp: string;
}

const MyComponent = (props: MyCustomProps & React.HTMLAttributes<...>) 
    => (...)
```

In typescript, an `&` in a type declaration refers to an *intersection type*. [You can read more in the typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types). The `props` object now combines the properties of `MyCustomProps` and the HTML attributes. (It's also worth learning about discriminated unions, or `or` types, which are notated with `|`. I find these more useful than intersections).

If you want to clean up your method signature, you could declare the type as follows:

```
interface MyCustomProps {...}
type ComponentProps = MyCustomProps & React.HTMLAtributes<...>;
```

However, this notation has now lost the conciseness of both the previous approaches - the `extends` syntax, and the `&` notation.

Comment: I would recommend use `extend` instead of `&`

Comment: Why do you recommend that approach @yozi ?

Comment: @sunpietro it has different semantic. One does _extend_ and another _intersection_. See my answer to this question. At the time I wrote it Typescript was not accurate enough with `&` 
I heard Typescript team had plans to fix it but what's the reason to rely on the "fix" if you simply can use `extend`