# Typescript React: How to override default html input element attribute prop types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a custom "Input" component and extend the default html input attributes (props).

However, I am also trying to override the default 'size' attribute using Typescript's Omit within my own interface definitions, but can't seem to get it to work.

(I've also tried Typescript's Pick/Exclude and a custom Override type, but get same error...)

Similar threads I've already tried:

- [Override the properties of an interface in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198713/override-the-properties-of-an-interface-in-typescript/49198999)
- [How extend React types to support html attributes as props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627493/how-extend-react-types-to-support-html-attributes-as-props)

```
import React from 'react';

type A = React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

interface InputProps extends Omit<A, 'size'> {
  size?: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
}

const Input = (props: InputProps) => {
  return <input {...props} />;
};
```

TS Error

```
(property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.input: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>
Type '{ size?: "sm" | "md" | "lg"; defaultChecked?: boolean; defaultValue?: string | number | readonly string[]; suppressContentEditableWarning?: boolean; ... 250 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: (event: TransitionEvent<...>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Type '{ size?: "sm" | "md" | "lg"; defaultChecked?: boolean; defaultValue?: string | number | readonly string[]; suppressContentEditableWarning?: boolean; ... 250 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: (event: TransitionEvent<...>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
    Types of property 'size' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `interface InputProps....` with

```
type InputProps = {
 size?: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
} & Omit<A, 'size'>;
```

---

Based on OP's comment,

```
const Input = ({ size, ...props }: InputProps) => {
  // if(size) do something...
  return <input {...props} />;
};
```

Comment: Hmm... the error still persists even with this definition

Comment: @TrieuNomad Its probably complaining about mismatching with the input since you are passing all props directly into input. Try out my new suggestion.

Comment: I ended up going with <input {...props} size={undefined} /> but your way works too. Will accept this as resolution since it fixes the ts error.

Comment: 1. Even when the `size` prop is not directly passed to the `input` element, we still get the same error.
2. When we export the type `InputProps` (to use it in another file), it gives the same error. 
What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The design flaw here isn’t the props that you’re accepting into your custom `Input` component.  It is that you are are then passing those same props down to the HTML `input` component, even though you already know that your `size` property differs from the expected `size` property.  That is what is reflected in the error that you’ve pasted here.

You do need to fix your type definition as explained by @silent.

But after doing that, you need to do something inside your `Input` component to map your custom `size` strings into numbers before you can pass them down to `input`.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment you have said that these are CSS class names.  So they need to be passed down to the `input` component in the `className` property, not the `size` property.

```
// sets default size to 'md' - you can change or remove this
const Input = ({size = 'md', className, ...props}: InputProps) => {
    // combine with existing class names
    const newClass = className + ' ' + size; // could trim redundant spaces but don't need to

    return (
        <input 
            {...props} 
            className={newClass}
        />;
};
```

You don't need to pass anything down to `size`. In fact this component cannot ever set anything to the `size` property on the `input` because we took `size` out when we used the spread operator (`{size = 'md', className, ...props}`).  `...props` is a "rest" parameter meaning that it has all the properties not otherwise extracted, so it will not include the `size` or `className` from the `InputProps`.

Comment: I don't really want to map the strings into designated number values, I just want to apply css classes. However I do get what you're saying, and I guess I could pass size={undefined} to the nested html input, which gets rid of the error. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Well in that case pass them down to the `className` property.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to replace your interface.

For example

```
export interface InputProps extends Omit<A,'size'> {
 size?: InputSize;
 /* other properties */
}

type A = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>,HTMLInputElement>;
type InputSize = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';

const Input = (props: InputProps) => {
 const { style, className, size = 'md', ...rest } = props;
 /* you don't have to pass a default value to size */

 return <input {...rest} />;
};
```